# Birt - onCreate

Tags: eclipse, birt

I have two images that I want to display according to a value from the dataset/dynamic text in the report.
I am getting errors when trying to do it.

```
if(this.getRowData().getExpressionValue("row[price]") == "$30" )
this.imageName = "check.JPG";  
else
this.imageName = "unchecked.JPG";
```

The error:

> org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: There are errors evaluating script "if(this.getRowData().getExpressionValue("row[price]") == "$30" ) this.imageName = "check.JPG"; else this.imageName = "unchecked.JPG";": TypeError: Cannot call method "getExpressionValue" of null (/report/body/image[@id="84"]/method[@name="onCreate"]#1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with the script - obviously getRowData() returns null, but I don't know why.

Anyway, I would solve this differently and use an image with "Image file in shared resources" and "resource file" is your file name. The file name must be an absolute path or relative to your "shared resources" folder. So your file name expression would be

```
row["price"] == "$30" ? "check.JPG" : "unchecked.JPG"
```